# How to promisify nightwatch windowHandles?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to promisify the nightwatch `windowHandles` [function](https://nightwatchjs.org/v17/api/windowHandles.html) within page objects. For example normally you can obtain window handles via the callback syntax:

```
this.api.windowHandles(result => result)
```

But I'd like to access the result outside of the callback:

```
const promisifyCallback = (fn) => new Promise(resolve => fn(result => resolve(result));

const handles = await promisifyCallback(this.api.windowHandles)
```

Seems like it should work (and it does work for other nightwatch functions like `getAttribute`) but for some reason the usage here throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isES6Async')
```

Comment: I'm surprised Promisifying the function isn't working. But if you can, you should consider migrating to the newer version of Nightwatch. v3 just got released as beta.

Comment: Maybe try `await promisifyCallback(this.api.windowHandles.bind(this.api))`? It's possible that the issue here is that the function definition of `windowHandles` is losing `this` context when passed into `promisifyCallback`.

Comment: Which version of nightwatch are you using? Calling windowHandles directly works just fine for me:

`const handles = await this.api.windowHandles();`

Comment: @BinayakGhosh version 1.3.4

Comment: @PriyanshGarg `this.bind` solved it! Thank you